# Post 500 error: axios behaves differently in two very similar but independent functions in asp.net react application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have the following two separate functions to `Post` and `Update` a comment. They are almost identical but the `UpdateComment` function throws `Post 500` error.

```
export function PostComment(commentData) {
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(dataOperationBegin());

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Create',
            data: {
                Content: commentData.Content,
                DoesAgree: commentData.DoesAgree,
                ParentPostId: commentData.ParentPostId,
                SubmissionId: commentData.SubmissionId,
                RubricItemId: commentData.RubricItemId
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(postCommentSuccess(response.data));
            })
            .catch(error => { dataOperationFailure(error) });
    };
}


export function UpdateComment(commentData) {
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(dataOperationBegin());

        axios(
            {
                method: 'post', url: 'api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Update',
                data: {
                    Id: commentData.Id,
                    Content: commentData.Content,
                    PostOwnerId: commentData.PostOwnerId,
                    ParentPostId: null,
                    SubmissionId: commentData.SubmissionId
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(updateCommentSuccess(response.data));
            })
            .catch(error => { dataOperationFailure(error) });
    };
}
```

Here on the server is the corresponding web api function for `api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Create`, which is invoked properly:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Student, Instructor")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Create")]
    public AssessmentDiscussionPostDTO Create([FromBody] AssessmentDiscussionPost post)
    {
```

Here is the othe web api function for `api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Update`, which is `NEVER` invoked:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Student, Instructor")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Update")]
    public AssessmentDiscussionPost Update([FromBody] AssessmentDiscussionPost post)
    {
```

I am spending hours on this but still no clue. Can someone at least guide me to identify actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is for sure related to BE, but why do you update things with POST, when you should use PATCH or PUT? Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: BE - its backend so in your case asp.net if there's 500 error even if FE(frontend) is wrong there should be some error handling